# GridLayout ,TableLayout in android

Tags: android, layout

in my project i have 9 image buttons which must come in 3 rows and 3 columns each image must be given a label or text beneath it as explaining it so is it good to use GridLayout or which layout will be best suitable for this situation and please suggest tutorial on suggested layout.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with it.

I would suggest you to use TableLayout if you have fixed no of views and will not change however if there is a chance of your views to increase then use GridView it uses adapter which manages memory it self.

Here is a good link to start off

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/07/android-layouts-linear-layout-relative-layout-and-table-layout/

Best of Luck